# Heatmap plot of a pandas dataframe - TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, typeerror

I have two pandas dataframes that on inspection look identical. One was created using the Pandas builtin:

```
df.corr(method='pearson')
```

While the other was created with a custom function:

```
def cor_matrix(dataframe, method):
    coeffmat = pd.DataFrame(index=dataframe.columns, 
columns=dataframe.columns)
    pvalmat = pd.DataFrame(index=dataframe.columns, columns=dataframe.columns)
    for i in range(dataframe.shape[1]):
        for j in range(dataframe.shape[1]):
            x = np.array(dataframe[dataframe.columns[i]])
            y = np.array(dataframe[dataframe.columns[j]])
            bad = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y))
            if method == 'spearman':
                corrtest = spearmanr(np.compress(bad,x), np.compress(bad,y))
            if method == 'pearson':
                corrtest = pearsonr(np.compress(bad,x), np.compress(bad,y))
            coeffmat.iloc[i,j] = corrtest[0]
            pvalmat.iloc[i,j] = corrtest[1]
    return (coeffmat, pvalmat)
```

Both look identical and have same type (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame) and their entries are also of same type (numpy.float64)

However when I try to plot these using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow((df))
```

Only the dataframe created with the pandas builtin function works. For the other dataframe I receive the error: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float. Can anyone explain what is going on, how the two dataframes are different and what can be done to address the error?

Edit - It looks as though there is one difference, when I convert the dataframes to a numpy array, the one that doesn't work has dtype = object at the end. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: You may always plot numpy arrays, `imshow(df.values.astype(np.float64))`.

Answer (score 0):

Amending the function to specify the dataframe as float fixed the issue:

```
def cor_matrix(dataframe, method):
    coeffmat = pd.DataFrame(index=dataframe.columns, columns=dataframe.columns)
    pvalmat = pd.DataFrame(index=dataframe.columns, columns=dataframe.columns)
    for i in range(dataframe.shape[1]):
        for j in range(dataframe.shape[1]):
            x = np.array(dataframe[dataframe.columns[i]])
            y = np.array(dataframe[dataframe.columns[j]])
            bad = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y))
            if method == 'spearman':
                corrtest = spearmanr(np.compress(bad,x), np.compress(bad,y))
            if method == 'pearson':
                corrtest = pearsonr(np.compress(bad,x), np.compress(bad,y))
            coeffmat.iloc[i,j] = corrtest[0]
            pvalmat.iloc[i,j] = corrtest[1]
    #This is to convert to float type otherwise can cause problems when e.g. plotting
    coeffmat=coeffmat.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    pvalmat=pvalmat.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    return (coeffmat, pvalmat)
```